# Is there a terminal command to list folder size and corresponding file sizes within on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr)?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Is there an Ubuntu 14.04 terminal command to list the folder size and give a break down of every file size in the folder and its size?

One of my folders is taking a great deal of space, and I'd like to identify which file(s) or subfolders are the culprit.

I know `du -sh` gives the total folder size and `ls -lah` in each folder gives me files/sub-folder sizes, but is there a way to get an overall snap shot of everything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is the `tree` command. Install it via `sudo apt-get install tree`, and type the following:

```
tree -h
```

From [man tree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/tree.1.html):

```
-h    Print  the size of each file but in a more human readable way, e.g. appending a size letter for kilo‐
      bytes (K), megabytes (M), gigabytes (G), terabytes (T), petabytes (P) and exabytes (E).
```

Done :)

Comment: Thanks this works great. Is there a way to show the total size within tree? I see the folder/file size it lists out but on the bottom report of total directors and files it scanned, is there a way to also list the size? (e.g., 96 directories, 307 files `total size`)

Comment: you are welcome. yes there is. add `--du` option like `tree -h --du`.

Answer (score 71):

I like to use simply:

```
du -chd 1 | sort -h
```

It outputs the total size of each sub-directory from the current directory location (the "1" above), as well as a total of all sub-directories, and sorts it by human-readable sizes:

[image: See how it looks here.]

Answer (score 7):

I found these helpful [top 10 disk usages](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/get-the-top-10-files-or-directories-on-ubuntu-linux/). For quick use, the command line is the following:

```
du -m | sort -nr | head -10
```

It lists all folders (including repetitive sub-folders) with most disk space usage sorted.

Answer (score 5):

Tree is nice, and I know that might be what you asked for. I wanted to present you with something slightly different though to help you find what you are looking for (what is consuming the most space):

```
du -lah|grep -v -e '^.*K[[:space:]]'|sort -r -n
```

You can also pipe to head to just get the top list:

```
du -lah|grep -v -e '^.*K[[:space:]]'|sort -r -n|head
```

I was trying to actually give this with `grep -v -e`..., but it doesn't seem to be working on the output for `du -lah` for some reason. It should be sufficient though.